# Custom routes rejected by GKE peer configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to expose the GKE apiserver private endpoint to my on-premise network, which is connected to VPC through a VPN tunnel.

The VPC network was created with custom mode (not auto mode) to allow custom routes.

There is a custom static route defined in VPC to reach my on-premise network.

GKE created an automatic VPC peering between my VPC and the GKE master nodes VPC on private cluster creation.

But when I enable custom routes export in 'Exchange custom routes' setting in VPC peering, I get 'rejected by peer configuration' for all of them: [Routes_rejected_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6e7C.png)

This is done in accordance with this part of docs:
[Setting up a private cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters)
section 'Routing between on-premises/cluster VPC and cluster master
'.

Any idea what might be wrong?

The only thing I could find is the part of docs the explains routing:
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes

and there's a note there:
"don't use destinations that fall into the 10.128.0.0/9 CIDR block because that block defines the current and future address space for subnet routes"

but I tried the same with addresses outside of this CIDR block with the same outcome.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Currently it is not feasible to expose the GKE apiserver from private endpoint. There is already an existing [feature request](http://issuetracker.google.com/140760929) regarding this issue. You may put additional comments there.

If you consider this issue important enough, please up-vote it to give it more visibility. In addition to that, if you want to create any Feature Request in future, you can follow the [guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) attached below.

Comment: Thanks Mahtab for the clarification! It was not entirely clear from the docs.